# Datepicker date range

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I use the fork https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker but I have some problems.

I want the datepicker to first show years, and after I click a year it shows month, and then it should close on month click so the date becomes "2013-01" for example.

I tried every possible combination on viewmode and minviewmode but can't get it to work in that particular order.

Here is my JS:

```
$('#from_date').datepicker({
    viewMode: "years", 
    minViewMode: "years",
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    startDate: '2008-01-01',
    endDate: 'y-12-31',
    autoclose: true
});
```

What is the correct code?

Is it also possible to hide the dates that are not in the date range? It shows years before 2008 and after 2013 (even if I can't click them).

Also the other problem is that the popup opens up on the div, and not on the calendar button (like the original script does). HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="input-append date" id="from_date" data-date="102/2012" data-date-format="yyyy-mm" data-date-viewmode="years" data-date-minviewmode="months">
<input name="date_from" id="dpMonths" class="dpMonths input-block-level" type="text" value="2008" /><span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Some more testing, it works better if I use:

     startView: "decade",
     minViewMode: "months",

But it is still a bit weird.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my own conclusion:

```
$('#from_date').datepicker({
    startView: "decade",
    minViewMode: "months",
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    startDate: '2008-01-01',
    endDate: 'y-12-31',
    autoclose: true
});

$('#to_date').datepicker({
    startView: "decade",
    minViewMode: "months",
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    startDate: '2008-01-01',
    endDate: 'y-12-31',
    autoclose: true
});
```

Still one problem I need help with. I need the "to_date" to end on the last day of the month. So the date range becomes 2013-01-01 to 2013-01-31 and not 2013-01-01 to 2013-01-01 like it does now.

Comment: Why don't you just use "yyyy-mm" as format (ignoring the date of month)? Wasn't that your original aim?